# Cant find any VPN in Netwrok Connections, cant connect to VPN

Tags: vpn

I use Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

To configure VPN from the section "Choose a Connection Type" there is no option for VPN  at the bottom. I tried to reinstall `network manager`, `network-manager-pptp` but the VPN option is still not there.

[No option to select VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKnfF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

install the packages `network-manager-pptp-gnome` and `network-manager-gnome` for GUI client, `network-manager` and `network-manager-pptp` packages are only for CLI interface.

Comment: It'a already installed, just checked it. But i still cant configure VPN from GUI.

Comment: do you don't have VPN option in network config in Dash too ? (where you configure already existent ethernet and wifi networks)

Comment: nope, i have nothing. How do i restore vpn connections to default?